# An app jar file that can load another GUI application within a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, plugins, jar, jpanel

How can I create an app jar file that can load in another GUI application within a `JPanel` (or similar component)?

Basically I want to create a Gui that can load an app from a jar file and run it inside a `JPanel` or a similar control.

Both the app and the GUI loader would be created by me. The only reason that I want them separate it so that other people can create apps for it as well using the same method.

I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to open a GUI inside another GUI? Why not just fully code one GUI and change visibility based on events?

Comment: It seems you want to provide a mechanism for application plug-ins?

Comment: Yes because I wanted to provide the ability for others to create apps that would run within it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may find some ideas for reaching your goal by reading the documentation of [JPF](http://jpf.sourceforge.net/). It may even be the solution for you, perhaps since it is a Plugin framework for Java.

Some of our students successfully used JPF for something similar in a European research project in 2004.